# stck at --> idealTree:lib: sill idealTree buildDeps

Tags: npm

facing this issue since today morning. not even a single command is working-> like npm i axios is also taking too long and this thing got stuck at this point. Dont't what is the exact issue, can anyone help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, any luck?